# Import error when trying to import Tkinter: cannot import name _cnfmerge

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I encountered this error when trying to import Tkinter

```
Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import Tkinter

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "Tkinter.py", line 3, in <module>

    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 7, in <module>

    from six.moves import tkinter_filedialog as FileDialog
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 203, in load_module
    mod = mod._resolve()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\FileDialog.py", line 12, in <module>
    from Dialog import Dialog

  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Dialog.py", line 4, in <module>
    from Tkinter import _cnfmerge

ImportError: cannot import name _cnfmerge
```

I am not sure what is going on here, but I think it might have to do with numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File "Tkinter.py", line 3, in <module>

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
```

The real Tkinter.py certainly does not contain any references to matplotlib.  You have another file with the same name on Python's search path, which is shadowing the real module.

Comment: You're really convinced given this statement "You have another file.."! Anyway, I would say: "you may have..".

Comment: Yes, you were correct. I had another file named Tkinter in a different folder which I was using previously. When I deleted the file the problem was solved. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I am building an application in python3+tkinter and had the same problem. I replaced 'NavigationToolbar2TkAgg' with 'NavigationToolbar2Tk' and it compiled successfully. Try replacing it and see if it works for you.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
```